# How to turn factors into columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

I have a dataframe with 700k rows and 6k factos, the structure is similar to this:

```
test1 = data.frame("date" = c("2018/11", "2018/10", "2018/11", "2018/10"), "season" = c("s01", "s02", "s01", "s02"), "product" = 
                                c("p01", "p01", "p02", "p02"), "qty" = c(110, 55, 80, 15))
```

(Update: I corrected the code to describe the result)
I need to bring every factor that appears in row to a column, like this:

```
test3 = data.frame("date" = c("2018/10", "2018/11"), "season" = c("s02", "s01"), "p01" = 
                 c(55, 110), "p02" = c(15, 80))
```

I was using `dplyr` to filter few factors, but in this case, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Look at `tidyr::spread()`.

Comment: @joran, really thanks! Worked well! I didn't know tidyr and I was thinking of doing some complex loop, hahaha. But worked well and simply! Thanks!

Comment: There are similar tools in the **data.table** and **reshape2** packages. The latter is older, tho, and not maintained actively anymore.

Comment: @Falves, please can you write your solution? because if I do the following is not really working properly: test1 %>% spread(product, qty)

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini, sorry for the delay, but in fact, I wrote the wrong code for test2 (I will correct it now in my description). I really needed it to group the results together. So, I did in my code: test2 = test1 %>% spread(product, qty).